# OutOfMemoryError in application loop, how to do better?

Tags: java, while-loop, out-of-memory

My application crashes with an OutOfMemoryError: Heap space. The loop is basically:

```
this.dbHandler = new DBHandler();
DataRetriever dataRetriever = new DataRetriever(this.dbHandler);
boolean loop = true;
System.out.println("Loop starts...");

while (loop == true) {
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  this.retrieveDataAndStoreInDB(dataRetriever);
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println("Total time: " + Long.toString((endTime-startTime)/1000) + " seconds.");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(60000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
System.out.println("Loop terminates.");
```

Obviously, Memory is allocated in `retrieveDataAndStoreInDB(dataRetriever)`.

1. Which tool(s) could I use to find where memory is allocated?
2. What kind of practices should I follow to avoid this? I would appreciate links to docs!

EDIT:
Ok, I realize my question is too unspecific.
First, my intention is to run the program indefinitely, like a demon. It should repeat data retrieval and db storage every 60 seconds.
Alternatively, I could run a cronjob every minute and exit the program, too, but execution time for that is more than 60 seconds unfortunately, while repeating with the loop takes only about 12 seconds. Plus, the next loop only runs if the first is finished.
loop==true is meant for the future, in case I would like to break the loop for some reason, but is not used at the moment. 
I can not show the code of retrieveDataAndStoreInDB() for now, because I am not at the computer which has the code. But it's going down deep, utilizing several classes I wrote on top of a large framework.

Maybe a better question would be:
Supposed I would like to repeat an execution flow every 60 seconds in Java, is my way appropriate, especially in terms of memory management? Yes, I'm a Java beginner :)

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Similarly, it would be 'obvious' to include the code in `retrieveDataAndStoreInDB` in your question...!

Comment: I'd start by allocating a method to get out of the loop.  (Also, `while(loop == true)`?  Just `while(loop)` is fine.  Or in this case `while(true)` since you never modify `loop`)

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler to help reduce your memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where do you change the loop value.

```
while (loop == true)
```

it is a infinitive loop. change the loop value inside the loop.

Comment: or remove the "Loop terminates" because it won't.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options to solve the OutOfMemory problem, which probably is caused by memory leak in the hidden method:

- either use a java profiler to inspect the runtime behavior by marking the objects and check which objects increase in time
- or you can create a java dump file when OutOfMemory error is thrown and later inspect the objects in the dump file with appropriate tool

Comment: Which Profiler and how?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not know what actually happens inside the function in question, so the lesson to learn would be to get to know your tools better before you use them. ;)

For the memory leak, there are several tools available to analyze what is actually happening (even in pre-compiled code), NetBeans for example comes with the [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) built-in, it is as well available as a plugin for Eclipse and as a stand-alone.

Using that tool you can let your program run and it will track up to each single memory allocation and where it happens for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Which tool(s) could I use to find where memory is allocated?

JProfiler or jvisualvm

2.What kind of practices should I follow to avoid this? I would appreciate links to docs!

follow the book [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)